# Is Qasr (shortening of prayers) allowed when traveling between your own houses?

Tags: salat-al-qasr

السلام عليكم ورحمة الله وبركاته,

Assume city A and city B are the minimum distance apart required for practicing Qasr, and I intend to stay there for only a couple days.

People in my locality are of the opinion that if you are traveling from one of your own properties in city A to one of your own properties in city B, Qasr is not valid. ie. The place you are traveling to must not be your own house/apartment/land/etc.

Is this a valid clause or not?

جزاك الله خير

Comment: What is their evidence to say so? Qasr is based on the distance, the place of your usual stay and the duration of your settlement at your destination.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Well, nothing more than the fact than “if you’re going home, you can’t be considered a traveler.”

Comment: Explain how would you go home? If you travelled over 89 kilometers?

Comment: @Medi1Saif Say I mainly stay in my house in city A. I only occasionally go to my house in city B, and there, Qasr is not valid since it’s my own house, allegedly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply speaking my understanding is that you mainly stay in your house in city A which therefore is your place of residence.
So once you go beyond the last house of this city intending to travel a distance that is longer than the minimum distance of qasr which is 88.704 kilometers according the view of the majority (maliki, shafi'i and hanbali) you may perform qasr (this value is based on Islamic Jurisprudence and its evidences of sheikh az-Zuhaili [الفقه الإسلامي وأدلته للزحيلي](http://www.islamilimleri.com/Kulliyat/Fkh/4Hanbeli/pg_081_0033.htm) while al-Jaziri in his Islamic Jurisprudence according the four sunni schools say it is 80.5 kilometers p.625 ff. The hanafis have not defined a distance rather than a time this travel would take under certain conditions.

Secondly when you arrive at your destination and have no clear intention when to leave it you count as a traveler as per all schools of jurisprudence (note that shafi'is from after a certain time of unintended settlement disagree), but when you made an intention about a period of time of stay or settlement the state of being a traveler could be lifted once you intention to stay is for longer than the maximum length of an intended stay: Hanafis say one must pray as if one is at home if one intends to stay more than 15 consecutive days at this location. Note this means even if you have prayed qasr to reach your destination once there if you intend to stay according to this 16 or more days you must pray full prayers. While if you went there with no intention to stay long, but circumstances hindered you to leave sooner you may still pray qasr, even if you amy stay there for years.
The shafi'is and malikis say if you intend to stay more than four days you should pray full prayers however it seems that they don't count both the day of arrival nor the day of departure (at least the shafi'is emphasized this).
The hanbaklis say if he intend to stay the time for more than 20 fard prayer.
Both the malikis and hanbalis say if one is held due to circumstances to stay longer one can still pray qasr as long as one didn't intend to stay in first place. The shafi'is here differ and say that if one stays at his destination longer than 18 days, not counting both the day of arrival and that of departure one should start praying full prayers as the prophet () shortened prayers for 18 consecutive days in the year of Fath Mekka while fighting Hawazan and then prayed full prayers.

See also islamqa #[105844](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/105844/the-distance-at-which-it-becomes-permissible-to-shorten-prayers)

Comment: So in a nutshell: you may pray qasr even at your own houses or own land, unless that is your PRIMARY place of residence?

Comment: Yes ownership of or in  a location is not criteria for qasr. Except with hanafis all sunni schools say that qasr can only be performed if you are not traveling to do a sin.